# python continue with except if condition not met

Tags: python, try-catch

I often find myself wanting to do something like this, I have something wrapped in try excepts like this

```
item= get_item()
try:
    do_work(item)
except SomeError as err:
    if err.code == 123:
        do_something(item)
    else:
        # Actually I don't want to do something with this error code... I want to handle in 'except'
except:
    put_back(item)
    raise
```

Is there a way to raise into the `except` block below from the else? (a `continue` would be nice) I end up doing something like the following which isn't as clean

```
item= get_item()
try:
    try:
        do_work(item)
    except SomeError as err:
        if err.code == 123:
            do_something(item)
        else:
            raise
 except:
     put_back(item)
     raise
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Do you control the exception that do_work throws?  You could just make a specific exception for error code "123" and catch that to `do_something` otherwise handle it by your exception block.

Comment: Nope, I thought of that but unfortunately I'm trying to handle specific `S3ResponseError` error codes from `boto`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using a recent enough python version (2.5 and up), you should switch to using a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) instead:

```
class WorkItemContextManager(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.item = get_item()
        return self.item

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        if exc_type is not None:
            if exc_type is SomeError and exc_value.code == 123:
                do_something(self.item)
                return True  # Exception handled
            put_back(self.item)
```

Then:

```
with WorkItemContextManager() as item:
    do_work(item)
```

The `__exit__` method can return True if an exception has been handled; returning None will instead re-raise any exceptions raised in the `with` block.

If not, you are looking for a `finally` block instead:

```
item = get_item()
try:
    do_work(item)
    item = None
except SomeError as err:
    if err.code == 123:
        do_something(item)
        item = None
finally:
    if item is not None:
        put_back(item)
```

The `finally` suite is guaranteed to be executed when the `try:` suite completes, *or* an exception has occurred. By setting `item` to `None` you basically tell the `finally` suite everything completed just fine, no need to put it back.

The `finally` handler takes over from your blanket `except` handler. If there has been an exception in `do_work`, `item` will not be set to None. If the `SomeError` handler doesn't catch the exception, or `err.code` is *not* 123, `item` will also not be set to None, and thus the `put_back(item)` method is executed.

Comment: The "finally" block will run even if there is not an exception raised. I see you put the "if item is not None", but that may not be the same as there being an error message.

Comment: Hm, I'm not convinced this is a nicer solution that the second example in the question.. I'd have to remember to set item to None everywhere where I handle an exception. Plus the case where item was None to begin with would mask any error handling

Comment: @GP89: The better method is to use a context manager; updated the answer to supply an example.

Comment: Think this is as good as  you can get. there's still the draw back of duplicating handler code in `except` and in `__exit__`, it could be put in a function, but still.. Plus someone coming to the code later might be confused why `except SomeException` isn't receiving error code 123. I think the best solution would be if the language changed so `continue` had the behaviour in my first example (I think currently `continue` in an except always raising a syntax error right? so it could be added theoretically) Where can I make suggestions for the language lol?

Comment: @GP89: That the point of a Context Manager: There is *no* need for an exception handler anymore because the CM is your exeption handler (see the `if exc_type is not None:` part, no exception means that is not executed).

Comment: Ah.. I see! I missed that point. I thought the context manager was just handling `SomeException` 123 and that was still inside of the `try except`. this is a nice solution :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to create a function (or series of functions) that wraps the method  throwing errors which you'd like to control. Something like...

```
def wrapper(arg):
    try:      
        do_work(arg)
    except SomeError as e:
        if e.code == 123:
           do_something(item)
           # Other possible cleanup code
        else:
           raise
```

...then, when you want to call it...

```
try:
    wrapper(arg)
except SomeError as e:
    put_back(arg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Context managers are excellent, but for some simple cases where you won't be reusing the logic anywhere else, they can be a bit heavy.

Instead of trying to have multiple `except` blocks, you can just test the exception inside a single `except` block:

```
item= get_item()
try:
    do_work(item)
except Exception as err:
    if isinstance(err, SomeError) and err.code == 123:
        do_something(item)
    else:
        put_back(item)
        raise
```

Note that this is pretty much what a context manager's `__exit__` method ends up looking like, anyway.

Be wary that code that really belongs in `finally` doesn't end up here.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to keep in mind what try-except flow is for, and one of their advantages is that they remove the need for status variables and status checks like

```
if not foo:
    # do something
```

Also, an Exception class should represent a specific kind of error. If you need to make further decisions about the kind of error in an except block, it's a good sign that the class isn't specific enough to represent the program state. Your best bet is to subclass SomeError and only catch the subclass in the first except. Then other instances of SomeError will fall through to the second except block.

Comment: I would, but unfortunately this isn't my code that throws the exception